# Are methodological questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are methodological questions like [this one](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-do-i-format-an-interlinear-gloss-for-html) on topic for the site?

Edit:

Pro: These are issues linguists deal with all the time, and we may have some special use cases.

Con: These aren't *linguistics* questions per se, and the answers may go far afield.

Comment: Post your opinions pro & con. I think it's on topic because it has an fairly easy objective answer & is a common problem your likely to run into while documenting a language (and it isn't likely to be addressed by reading up on general typography).

Answer (score 5):

Pro: These questions are of interest to linguists, one would look for the answers on the linguistics site, someone googling for this question would be interested in the rest of the site and there is no reason to assume that these questions would overwhelm the site or get no answers or be sorely missed on other stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 4):

I think they are generally on topic.  They may not be "linguistics questions" but they certainly are questions about the study of language.  As someone who is first entering the field academically, I would say they are also some of the most useful.  Given enough time I can find information on obscure dialectic construct X (or whatever), but explanations of how other linguists tend to go about their work is often wholly undocumented.

Of course there will be bad apples, but on the whole I think these questions are great and would help foster the community (ours here at SE and linguistics overall).

Answer (score 4):

I know that the TeX Stack Exchange has a fairly active community of linguists contributing to it.  There are also many TeX experts who are not linguists, who can contribute to solving problems.  I assume there is a similar site for web design/HTML.

Questions that are purely about **formatting** belong on another Stack Exchange website, since there is nothing inherently linguistic about them.  They will also benefit from the participation of people with no interest in linguistics, but a knowledge of a particular formatting language.

Answer (score 1):

I would say on topic. Phira's point is a good one. I don't think we can ever see a solid improvement in the stats if we keep rejecting questions as not sufficiently on topic or already dealt with in other forums.